# remove number and special character using owa_pattern

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, toad, plsqldeveloper

Using owa_pattern.change in oracle 9i.

Is it possible to remove a number and the trailing special character (pls note only the trailing) special character in a string?

I refer to special character as characters that is neither a word nor a number. 
e.g _ , # , @ ,$ etc ...

For example.

String = TEST_STRING_10

desired output would be TEST_STRING (notice only the trailing special character _ was removed).

I have already figured out how to remove the number but is stuck in the special character part.

I have this code so far.

```
OWA_PATTERN.CHANGE (string, '\d', '', 'g');
```

Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
OWA_PATTERN.CHANGE (string, '[^a-zA-Z]+$', '');
```

Regular expression

```
[^a-zA-Z]+    any character except: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' 
              (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
 $            before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If it's ok can you break down what this code do?'[^a-zA-Z]+$'

Comment: seems like you edited your first answer which actually worked. This one only removes an underscore. :(

Comment: awesome! there are only few documentations i've found in the internet regarding owa_pattern. your answer helped me so much. thank you.

Comment: The second one does not work but the first one does the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
DECLARE
    result VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    string := 'TEST_STRING_10';
    result := REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '([[:alnum:]_].*)_[[:digit:]]+', '\1', 1, 0, 'c');
END;
```

Comment: sadly we are still in 9i and regexp is not available. owa_pattern is the closest i can find.

Comment: @user2058738 It seems that you already got the answer, good :)